# Spearmans and variable units

Tags: correlation

Both my variables for correlation (Spearmans given small n of 17) relate to time (seconds for x, and  minutes and secs for y). Should I standardize the units before entering into analysis. I get different answers if I try both ways, which is correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spearman's, which is based on ranks, it will not make any difference if you standardize or not, since standardizing doesn't change the ranks. E.g.

```
x <- runif(17)*10 
y <- runif(17)*4
cor(x,y,method = "spearman")
stdx <- (x-mean(x))/sd(x)
stdy <- (y-mean(y))/sd(y)
cor(stdx, stdy, method = "spearman")
```

However, you can use Pearson's correlation with low N. Which one to use depends on the distribution of the variables and what you are trying to find out.

Comment: Many thanks. That's what I thought but I can't get my head round that I get vastly different answers depending on the units I use! Because the distribution of 2 of the variables are non-normal I thought it best just to stick with Spearman for all the vars (4 different (test 1,2,3,4) being correlated against one. (performance).
Really appreciate your time in replying.

Comment: @JJ01 I've merged your two unregistered accounts. Please, [register](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) this one.